# Recurrance for how many ways to color this line?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations

If you have a line with n segments, how many ways can you color it with the colors Green, Blue and Red, if there are no adjacent blue segments?

My answer is $ 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} $

My reasoning:

```
Possibilities

______________G  (n-1)
______________R  (n-1)
______________B  (n-1-1 = n-2  (Don't count the BB ending)
```

Comment: By considering all cases you can find $a_1=3$, $a_2=8$ and $a_3=22\ne2a_2+a_1$, so your recurrence is wrong.  **Hint**: look at your third case more closely.

Comment: Hint 2: let $b_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ without 2 blues that also don't start with a blue.

Comment: Got it, so it should be $ 2_{n-1}+ 2a_{n-2} $  ?

Comment: What is a $2_{n-1}$ ?